# How to read and output how many Bytes a folder has in it using C++ 17 filesystem on windows

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I have a C++ program that takes a directory, like "D:\P4Test", and attempts to tell me how many bytes are in each subfolder and file within that directory. The code I currently have looks like this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <sstream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    string path = "D:\\P4Test";
    for (const auto& entry : directory_iterator(path)) {
        cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
        uintmax_t fsize = file_size(entry.path());
        cout << " ||| " << fsize << endl;
    }
}
```

Yes, it has a lot of unnecessary includes and such, but that's for future things.

When I run this code, I don't get what I want. Here's a picture of what's in that directory, and the output.

[image]

As you can see, the output looks good, but it does not give me the bytes for what's in the folders called "Two" & "Three".

Both folders have a text file in them that's 5 bytes, but they report back 0.

Can anyone help me figure out why, and show me how to make the folders show their bytes, or direct me to where I can figure this out?

Comment: Most likely because, for your filesystem, you have to recurse into each directory and individual add up the size of each file in each directory. As far as a subdirectory itself, its size only represents the amount of disk space the directory itself takes up. It only, perhaps, takes a few bytes to record the name of a single file in a directory, and its associated metadata, even though the file itself is ten terabytes big. But the size of the directory, itself, is just those few bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do a recursive file size check, but you do not actually recurse into the directories. 1 way to do this is to stasrt with a function gets all of the file sizes:

```
void folder_size(std::filesystem::path path) {
    for (const auto& entry : directory_iterator(path)) {
        cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
        uintmax_t fsize = file_size(entry.path());
        cout << " ||| " << fsize << endl;
    }
}
```

Now we simply a special case to deal with if the file type is a directory, we can do this with `std::filesystem::directory_entry::is_directory`:

```
if (entry.is_directory()) {
    // Handle the directory
}
```

So how do we handle the directory, well we have a function that we made that takes a directory path and goes through it. Lets call that:

```
if (std::filesystem::is_directory(entry.path())) {
    folder_size(entry.path())
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
void folder_size(std::filesystem::path path) {
    for (const auto& entry : directory_iterator(path)) {
        cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
        uintmax_t fsize = file_size(entry.path());
        cout << " ||| " << fsize << endl;
        if (std::filesystem::is_directory(entry.path())) {
            folder_size(entry.path())
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** All of the above is example code. No compilation check has been conducted.

Comment: Unfortunately I get errors and I can't run the code. It highlights the word 'entry' in "folder_size(entry.path)" as no suitable user-defined conversion from "const std::filesystem::path" to "std::string" exists.

Comment: This is example code. I am sure that you can put in some time to sort out these issues. I also recommend you use `path`s instead of `string`s.

Comment: Alright cool, thx for the idea and assistance.